# How to report the results of a complex path analysis?

Tags: amos, structural-equation-modeling

I started with a model with 5 IVs and 7 DVs. This model had a poor fit (RMSEA = 0.405, CFI=0.760 or so). Most of my hypotheses were not confirmed, i.e. many regression coefficients were not significant, so there were no relationships between many variables.

Next, I started to prune the model, eliminating the paths with non-significant coefficients, and removing two variables that seemed useless (one IV and one DV). Finally, the re-specified model was good (RMSEA = 0.042, CFI=0.982). Also, all the coefficients were significant.

My question is: how to report the results in my paper? Should I present both models and say "model 1 was not good so I modified it to model 2"? Or should I report only the second model and say something like "out of my hypotheses, only this and this are supported"? What are the standards and the common practices in the scientific world? Any suggestion would help.

(N.B. I am aware that I have used SEM in an exploratory manner, though it is a confirmatory technique, but I had to do that. I had a hard time collecting the data and I simply couldn't settle for the initial poor model.)

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the honest thing to do is to present both models. You used SEM in two different ways (described by Joreskog in a chapter in the book "Testing structural equation models", edited by Bollen and Long).  You first used a strictly confirmatory approach - this failed, as it almost always does. You then moved to a model generating approach.

Ideally, you should cross validate on a new dataset (or a new half of your dataset) because you are at risk of capitalizing on chance.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, Jeremy! The idea of cross-validation is really interesting, I will try it. Here's what I'm thinking... Since I have started with so many variables (12, 5 IVs plus 7 DVs) isn't it normal to start with an exploration, in order to see which variables really correlate, and then simplify the model based on the findings?

Comment: Yes, it's normal. But it's not how SEM was originally planned, so it's sometimes sort of frowned upon. But that chapter discusses it.